# Why C99 has such an odd restriction for universal character names?

Tags: c, unicode

[6.4.3 Universal character names](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.4.3.html)

> A universal character name shall not specify a character whose short identifier is less than 00A0 other than 0024 ($), 0040 (@), or 0060 (`), nor one in the range D800 through DFFF inclusive.

Besides the fact that it is no longer "universal" with restrictions like this, I can't think of good reasons for such a restriction. Anyone knows the backstory?

Comment: Think about what characters go in the forbidden ranges. Control characters, characters which already have other meanings, and surrogates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`D800` through `DFFF` inclusive are not valid code points; they are high and low surrogates, which can only be found in pairs in UTF-16 encoding in order to represent code points outside of the base plane.

The other restriction avoids having a universal character name collide with a character which could be represented in the C character set, for the benefit of compilers which don't bother resolving universal character names into their unicode equivalents. So the compiler is under no obligation to recognize a <kbd>+</kbd> written as `\u002B` or to know that `a` and `\u0061` represent the same name. (<kbd>$</kbd>, <kbd>@</kbd> and <kbd>`</kbd> are not valid in a C program outside of comments and character strings, so they do not require any special attention from the lexer.)

The range of code points less than `A0` also includes control characters and whitespace. (C does not consider `\u00A0` to be whitespace.)