# Restrictions to Unicode escape sequences in C11

Tags: c, unicode, escaping, string-literals, unicode-escapes

Why is there a restriction for Unicode escape sequences (`\unnnn` and `\Unnnnnnnn`) in C11 such that only those characters outside of the basic character set may be represented? For example, the following code results in the compiler error: `\u000A is not a valid universal character`. (Some Unicode "dictionary" sites even give this invalid format as canon for the C/C++ languages, though admittedly these are likely auto-generated):

```c
static inline int test_unicode_single() {
        return strlen(u8"\u000A") > 1;
}
```

While I understand that it's not exactly necessary for these basic characters to supported, is there a technical reason why they're not? Something like not being able to represent the same character in more than one way?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I don't see how that applies to my question. The question uses 0x000A (U+000A) (LF - Line Feed) as an example Unicode character, represented in 4 hex digits.

Comment: How about this: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.3p2  *A universal character name shall not specify a character whose short identifier is less than 00A0 other than 0024 ($), 0040 (@), or 0060 ('), nor one in the range D800 through DFFF inclusive.*

Comment: @EugeneSh. That's useful, especially the footnote. But the question still remains - _why_? Is it a security concern?

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20158506

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's precisely to avoid alternative spellings.

The primary motivations for adding Universal Character Names (UCNs) to C and C++ were to:

- allow identifiers to include letters outside of the basic source character set (like `ñ`, for example).
- allow portable mechanisms for writing string and character literals which include characters outside of the basic source character set.

Furthermore, there was a desire that the changes to existing compilers be as limited as possible, and in particular that compilers (and other tools) could continue to use their established (and often highly optimised) lexical analysis functions.

That was a challenge, because there are huge differences in the lexical analysis architectures of different compilers. Without going into all the details, it appeared that two broad implementation strategies were possible:

1. The compiler could internally use some single universal encoding, such as UTF-8. All input files in other encodings would be transcribed into this internal encoding very early in the input pipeline. Also, UCNs (*wherever they appeared*) would be converted to the corresponding internal encoding. This latter transformation could be conducted in parallel with continuation line processing, which also requires detecting backslashes, thus avoiding an extra test on every input character for a condition which very rarely turns out to be true.
2. The compiler could internally use strict (7-bit) ASCII. Input files in encodings allowing other characters would be transcribed into ASCII with non-ASCII characters converted to UCNs prior to any other lexical analysis.

In effect, both of these strategies would be implemented in Phase 1 (or equivalent), which is long before lexical analysis has taken place. But note the difference: strategy 1 converts UCNs to an internal character coding, while strategy 2 converts non-representable characters to UCNs.

What these two strategies have in common is that once the transcription is finished, there is no longer any difference between a character entered directly into the source stream (in whatever encoding the source file uses) and a character described with a UCN. So if the compiler allows UTF-8 source files, you could enter an `ñ` as either the two bytes 0xc3, 0xb1 or as the six-character sequence `\u00D1`, and they would both end up as the same byte sequence. That, in turn, means that every identifier has only one spelling, so no change is necessary (for example) to symbol table lookup.

Typically, compilers just pass variable names through the compilation pipeline, leaving them to be eventually handled by assemblers or linkers. If these downstream tools do not accept extended character encodings or UCNs (depending on implementation strategy) then names containing such characters need to be "mangled" (transcribed) in order to make them acceptable. But even if that's necessary, it's a minor change and can be done at a well-defined interface.

Rather than resolve arguments between compiler vendors whose products (or development teams) had clear preferences between the two strategies, the C and C++ standards committees chose mechanisms and restrictions which make both strategies compatible. In particular, both committees forbid the use of UCNs which represent characters which already have an encoding in the basic source character set. That avoids questions like:

- What happens if I put `\u0022` inside a string literal:

  ```
    const char* quote = "\u0022";
  ```

  If the compiler translates UCNs to the characters they represent, then by the time the lexical analyser sees that line, `"\u0022"` will have been converted to `"""`, which is a lexical error. On the other hand, a compiler which retains UCNs until the end would happily accept that as a string literal. Banning the use of a UCN which represents a quotation mark avoids this possible non-portability.
- Similarly, would `'\u005cn'` be a newline character? Again, if the UCN is converted to a backslash in Phase 1, then in Phase 3 the string literal would definitely be treated as a newline. But if the UCN is converted to a character value only after the character literal token has been identified as such, then the resulting character literal would contain two characters (an implementation-defined value).
- And what about `2 \u002B 2`? Is that going to look like an addition, even though UCNs aren't supposed to be used for punctuation characters? Or will it look like an identifier starting with a non-letter code?

And so on, for a large number of similar issues.

All of these details are avoided by the simple expedient of requiring that UCNs cannot be used to spell characters in the basic source character set. And that's what was embodied in the standards.

Note that the "basic source character set" does not contain every ASCII character. It does not contain the majority of the control characters, and nor does it contain the ASCII characters `$`, `@` and `` ` ``. These characters (which have no meaning in a C or C++ program outside of string and character literals) can be written as the UCNs `\u0024`, `\u0040` and `\u0060` respectively.

Finally, in order to see what sort of knots you need to untie in order to correctly lexically analyse C (or C++), consider the following snippet:

```
const char* s = "\\
n";
```

Because continuation lines are dealt with in Phase 1, prior to lexical analysis, and Phase 1 only looks for the two-character sequence consisting of a backslash followed by a newline, that line is the same as

```
const char* s = "\n";
```

But that might not have been obvious looking at the original code.